# Fatal error when compiling #include <sys/uio.h> on project [windows]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

trying to compile a file for class, using the mingw compiler on windows 10. Compiling with g++ gives me an error stating

```
\projectFile.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o D:\GitHub\GitRepo\projectFile.exe D:\GitHub\GitRepo\projectFile.o   
D:\GitRepo\projectFile.cpp:16:20: fatal error: sys/uio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

From what ive read this header file

```
#include <sys/uio.h>
```

is a unix header and is generally included with most unix build environments. I am working on Windows 10 build and have been unsuccessful in trying to get this to work. Is there a work around for windows using different headers? Is there a while to install this file somehow?

The project is a generalized XML parser that as a student my job is to extract functions from the main file so that they can be reused (OOP design space)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "XMLParser.hpp"
```

Built on Windows 10 (lastest build) with Mingw-64  (lastest version)
This will not compile for me

Comment: You might get further problems, unistd.h and sys/types.h are POSIX headers as well... I wouldn't try to replace the entire headers, but instead try to spot which functions and data types are used from and resolve these accordingly. Prefer replacements from C++ standard libraries (if code was written for older standard), otherwise you might need OS specific build switches (`#ifdef WIN32 #else #endif`).

Comment: The first thing I would do in your situation is comment out the problematic `#include` line to see just how dependent the project is on it. (How many identifiers become undefined when that file is not available?) Best case scenario: the `#include` is an unused legacy line that no one bothered to remove. Worst case scenario: every function, constant, etc. from `sys/uio.h` is used somewhere. Find out where you are on this spectrum before designing a plan to overcome the situation.

Comment: so commenting the header out allowed the code to compile, but im supposed to pass it a file, but it no longer reads in the file (we are using the xml file of a linux kernel for testing purposes). So although it didnt break any identifiers or dependent functions, it does not work correctly which when shown in class this same file it worked.(But it worked on my machine joke).insert

Comment: Then find the place at which the file will be read in. File IO is a pretty old part of C++ libraries, originating back to times when they still were called *'standard template libraries'* (STL). Have a look at [`<fstream>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem creating this uio.h file in sys directory of mingw64

```
#ifndef SYS_UIO_H
#define SYS_UIO_H

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct iovec
{
    void    *iov_base;  /* Base address of a memory region for input or output */
    size_t   iov_len;   /* The size of the memory pointed to by iov_base */
};

 ssize_t readv(int fildes, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);
ssize_t writev(int fildes, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);

#endif /* SYS_UIO_H */
```